# Can I deploy Chat Bot at customer premise?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-watson, watson, amazon-lex

I have chatbots on AWS and IBM Watson. I just want to know can I deploy my bots on customer side rather than a cloud? My aim is to deploy chatbot on my machine.

Comment: Do you... have source code? If so compile that bad boy and run it. Otherwise you might want to post this on [Super User](https://SuperUser.com).

Comment: My code is at AWS.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

Both of these chat bot services are managed services and not available for exporting.